# React-Select Async loadOptions - get data on failure

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-select

In my `React Redux` application I'm using `react-select` library to display a select box. specifically using `AsyncSelect` to get the data from an API.
I have set the authentication with session token stored in browser sent with every request. This session token becomes invalid after few hours so I have a special scenario when the user sends an invalid token, I make a validation API call to validate and refresh the session token, and execute the original call once again. the problem is that my **loadOptions** **method already executed** (with unauthorized failure reponse from the api) so there is no data.

I've tried storing the search values inside the global state so I'll be able to load it from there (and not from the response, since its failed) but the 2nd request data arrives only after loadOptions
method execution.

```
loadWorkers(inputValue, callback) {
    if (inputValue == null || inputValue.length < 3) { // not executing with less than 3 characters
        callback([]);
        return;
    }
    this.props.actions.getWorkersByName(inputValue, includeLeft).then(response => {
        let workers = [];
        if (response && !response.error)
            workers = getResponseData(response);
        else { // error, get data from global state.
            workers = this.props.quickSearchResults;
        }
        callback(workers);
    });
}
```

My question is, is there a way to dynamically call loadOptions every time global state value changes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same question.